# Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, centos6, drush

I have CentOS 6.6 with PHP 5.5.27 and Drupal 7.34

```
PHP 5.5.27 (cli) (built: Jul 10 2015 23:40:40)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

I've tried all latest 6,7,8 branches of Drush. When I type "drush -d -v status" I get an unrecoverable error (the error is the same on all branches of drush):

```
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_full() [0.19 sec, 5.13 MB]                                           [bootstrap]
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at                                 [warning]
/root/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/output.inc:38) common.inc:698 [0.96 sec, 31.89 МБ]
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error. [1.06 sec, 32.8 МБ]
```

I can't figure out what's wrong. Can anyone advise please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just try drush status and post its response.

Comment: @pal4life I have posted "drush -d -v status" output in my original post.

Comment: Hi I meant drush status without any options, that can give a much more standard response and may help find similar use cases.

Comment: @pal4life Without any options it just returns "Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error", so that's why I icnluded additional debug flags trying to shed more light on what's happening there.

Comment: This is a common error if you are invoking drush from outside a drupal webroot folder. So try using drush from that environment and hopefully that should work for you.

Comment: You may find some hints in /admin/reports/dblog about issues with a particular file. Headers already sent usually indicates there is a script that is printing or echoing something where it shouldn't be (or could even be as simple as a space before the opening <?php tag or after the closing ?> tag in a module.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in another comment, look for closing ?> tags at the end of custom modules, specifically any blank spaces after the >...but just remove the ?> to be in compliance.

A way to fix is to disable module by module until drush gives you a positive response. This will narrow down the code to review.

Also look at any hook_init() functions to see if anything is getting sent to the browser  then check the weight of the module in the system table. If it is too low, it may cause an issue.